# Vertical bar (|) Unicode replacement

Tags: xml, unicode, csv, separator

We are using the vertical bar `|` (`&#124;`) character as a field separator in one of our modules. so the users should not use this character in a title.

If they do use it, I would like to replace it with a similar character.

**Is there a Unicode replacement for it?** The only character that I have found and looks similar to it is broken vertical bar `¦` (`&#166;`).

Comment: `|` is Unicode. How about escaping typed `|`s instead?

Comment: @MattBall, What I meant is a Unicode replacement for the Ansi '|' char, as suggested by Juozas Domarkas. I can't use escape for it (in the limited time I have), but I know it's should have been the correct way.

Comment: What in the world is “Ansi”, anyway? Sounds like yet another confusing and meaningless Microsoft deceit.  It makes no sense. Please use standard language not proprietary jargon.

Comment: @tchrist I think you meant to `@ZigiZ`, but anyway, "ANSI" is a misnomer from the Windows world used as a synonym for "Windows-1252."

Comment: @MattBall Yup, I fixed the @ ZigiZ bit, but you’re too quick on the draw. :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I do not understand what you really need. Do you need to change the separator sequence to something guaranteed not to exist in the dataset?

If so, then that’s what Unicode’s 66 “non-character” code points are specifically designed for. You can use them as internal sentinels knowing that they cannot occur in valid data.

If you’re just looking for a visual lookalike, that’s very different. I would not suggest that, because there are lots of confusables. Here are just a few of those:

```
U+0007C ‭ |  GC=Sm SC=Common       VERTICAL LINE
U+000A6 ‭ ¦  GC=So SC=Common       BROKEN BAR
U+002C8 ‭ ˈ  GC=Lm SC=Common       MODIFIER LETTER VERTICAL LINE
U+002CC ‭ ˌ  GC=Lm SC=Common       MODIFIER LETTER LOW VERTICAL LINE
U+02016 ‭ ‖  GC=Po SC=Common       DOUBLE VERTICAL LINE
U+023D0 ‭ ⏐  GC=So SC=Common       VERTICAL LINE EXTENSION
U+02758 ‭ ❘  GC=So SC=Common       LIGHT VERTICAL BAR
U+02759 ‭ ❙  GC=So SC=Common       MEDIUM VERTICAL BAR
U+0275A ‭ ❚  GC=So SC=Common       HEAVY VERTICAL BAR
U+02AF4 ‭ ⫴  GC=Sm SC=Common       TRIPLE VERTICAL BAR BINARY RELATION
U+02AF5 ‭ ⫵  GC=Sm SC=Common       TRIPLE VERTICAL BAR WITH HORIZONTAL STROKE
U+02AFC ‭ ⫼  GC=Sm SC=Common       LARGE TRIPLE VERTICAL BAR OPERATOR
U+02AFE ‭ ⫾  GC=Sm SC=Common       WHITE VERTICAL BAR
U+02AFF ‭ ⫿  GC=Sm SC=Common       N-ARY WHITE VERTICAL BAR
U+0FF5C ‭ ｜ GC=Sm SC=Common       FULLWIDTH VERTICAL LINE
U+0FFE4 ‭ ￤ GC=So SC=Common       FULLWIDTH BROKEN BAR
```

Comment: What I was hopping for was a *visual lookalike*. I should not have mentioned the delimiter part in my question - my bad. (the delimiter is not used in csv nor xml nor a field separator - It's too complicated to explain, so I wont...). but since you mentioned the 66 non-character code points, it would be nice to know which Unicode block they hold.

Comment: @ZigiZ The 66 non-character code points are “the 32 between U+FDD0 and U+FDEF, and the 34 code points U+FFFE, U+FFFF, U+1FFFE,
U+1FFFF, ... U+10FFFE, U+10FFFF.  Some people are under
 the mistaken impression that these are "illegal", but that
 is not true.  An application or cooperating set of
 applications can legally use them at will internally; but
 these code points are "illegal for open interchange".”

Comment: I use '\t' the tab

Answer (score 6):

There's a ['light vertical bar'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2758/index.htm) in Unicode: ❘, codepoint U+2758

Comment: It's a good answer, however there is a big limitation with fonts that do support this char :( I have tried it (`&#10072;`) in IE9 and it shows an ugly square.

Comment: And that, my friend, is why we use escape characters.

Comment: U+2502 tends to be well supported.

Comment: @ZigiZ Font support is immaterial.  We’re talking about code points here. Always and only play strictly by the numbers, and do not get bogged down by the vicissitudes of end-user presentation forms. GUIs are irrelevant to code points.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/007c/index.htm

See Also:

- latin letter dental click U+01C0
- hebrew punctuation paseq U+05C0
- divides U+2223
- light vertical bar U+2758

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, i don't know why it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Unicode, and indeed ASCII before it, has characters that are designed to be used for exactly your situation.

There are characters that are designed to be used as:

- Unit Separator (`␟`): Between fields of a record, or members of a row.
- Record Separators (`␞`): End of a record or row

> **Note:** Those characters you see are the *visual representations*:
>
> - `␟` [U+241F](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/241f/index.htm) - Symbol for unit separator
> - `␞`: [U+241E](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/241e/index.htm) - Symbol for record separator

In reality you aren't supposed to use *those* characters (␟, ␞). The actual characters go back to the ASCII days:

```
Character         Symbol  ASCII  Unicode  Unicode name
----------------  ------  -----  -------  -------------------------
Unit separator        ␟  0x0F   U+001F   Information separator one
Record separator      ␞  0x1E   U+001E   Information separator two
```

Unfortunately the actual *record separator* and *unit separator* characters are unprintable:

- Field separator: `?`
- Record separator: `?`

Which is why it is nice that the *symbols* exist for those characters:

- Field separator: `␟`
- Record separator: `␞`

And nothing stops you from using those characters themselves:

```
AUD␟Australian dollar␟0.923␞
BRL␟Brazilian real␟0.3443␞
CNY␟Chinese renminbi␟0.1926␞
EUR␟European euro␟1.5009␞
JPY␟Japanese yen␟0.01229␞
MXN␟Mexican peso␟0.06894␞
NOK␟Norwegian krone␟0.154␞
RUB␟Russian ruble␟0.02074␞
CHF␟Swiss franc␟1.3448␞
GBP␟UK pound sterling␟1.6844␞
VND␟Vietnamese dong␟0.000057␞
```

I know you said you wanted something *visually* similar, but, it's nice when there's an exact intended solution for a given problem.