# How to escape '|" character into an org-mode table

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am building some tables in org-mode and I need to enter "||" into the table (for the logical OR command) and nothing I try turns the two characters off as table constructors.

I've tried single quotes, double quotes, backticks and prefacing them with '\'. I've also tried every permutation of using ':=' to get a literal string and they don't work.

// Tony Williams

Comment: \vert{} worked for me. Consult the org-symbols manual. http://orgmode.org/worg/org-symbols.html .

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to insert "|" in org-mode table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876048/how-to-insert-in-org-mode-table)

Answer (score 6):

Depending on what you want to do with the output of the table, you could use alternative unicode characters that look like vertical pipes (or double vertical pipes).  Examples:

```
This is the pipe character written twice (as for logical OR):
||
Those are similar (or not too different) looking unicode characters
‖ - ¦¦ - ❘❘
```

Of course, this won't work for you if you are not just interested in the looks (but escaping pipes would not work either).

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572627/vertical-bar-unicode-replacement) more unicode characters you might like better than those 3 above

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that you can use HTML entities in org-mode tables for output via pandoc.

`\vert{}` doesn't work but I went to the table pointed to by MrSpock and tried the HTML entity and the output when run through pandoc was perfect. `&#124;&#124;` gives me '||'. I also tested a few other HTML entities and they also worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the goal is to export your notes, then

```
$\lvert\mathbb{N}\rvert$
```

would be an equivalent of

```
$|\mathbb{N}|$
```

Answer (score -1):

Character is:  **\vert**
Example: `a \vert\ b  -> a | b`